# loading multiple ipy notebooks from another notebook

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook

how will it work with more than one notebook?

let's say i'm in notebook C which relies on ipy notebooks A and B
and b relies on A.

will i be able to do:

```
os.chdir(a_Path)
    %run ./a.ipynb

os.chdir(b_Path)
    %run ./b.ipynb
```

since i get :

ERROR:root:File `'./a.ipynb.py'` not found.

after trying to run Notebook B.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the campatible commands that can work together.

This changes the working directory:

```
%cd some/path/to_the_ipynb
```

This runs a Jupyter notebook in that directory:

```
%run ./notebook_b.ipynb
```

Hope this helps.